# text alignment - Android GravityFlags.Right cutting off first character of each line

Tags: android, html, layout, xamarin.android, alignment

I am working on a project that has RTL and LTR languages in it, and am currently modifying the layout such that controls are compatible with RTL languages, generally meaning that side-by-side text/control paradigms need to be reversed. In order to align the text in a certain `TextView` to the right, I am using `GravityFlags.Right`, but that's causing the first character of every line of text to be cut off. I have tried many different combinations of `GravityFlags` to get this to work, but no dice. Putting a non-breaking space at the beginning of the translation works, but only for the first line. And it's impossible to know where every line will break. See example below...

Control with text using `GravityFlags.Center`:

[image: CenterText]

vs.
Control with text using `GravityFlags.Right`:

[image: RightText]

I have tried to remove the margins around the outside of the control, which simply pushes the control and the text to the edges of the screen, and the result is the same. The text being clipped to the right is clearly seen in the second picture.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try using padding on the layout holding the texts?

Comment: @PrinceAli - I did. This actually shifts the text element inwards to the left, but still preserves the cut-off issue.

Comment: Can you share the codes to this layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support **LTR** and **RTL**, you should better use `start/end` instead of `left/right`. You could have a try, more info can refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages).

[image]

In addition, not forget to add `android:supportsRtl` in **[AndroidManifest.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#android)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" ... />
    <application ... android:supportsRtl="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`android:minSdkVersion` should above `17`.